# WP subdomain multisite siteurl/home settings (no registration)

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have the following setup:

The primary domain is example.com. I'm not using this site for any other purpose than managing the other (sub)sites. All the core files are hosted at this address.

I'm using subdomains (not folders), so sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, etc. to create new instances.

I'm disallowing registrations, so I'm defaulting to another site altogether in case nothing's there at the subdomain.

The wp-config.php contains the following relevant settings:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE',true);

define('MULTISITE',true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL',true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE','www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE','/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE',1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE',1);
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT','https://www.default.com');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
define('ABSPATH',dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME','custom-folder');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR',ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL',WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

Now, my question is: assuming I've created a subdomain named "sub1.example.com"
for the new domain "landing-page1.com", what addresses should I ideally use for the Siteurl and Home fields in site-settings.php at the sub1.example.com instance?

Because currently I'm running into an issue where I've entered "http://www.landing-page1.com" for both fields, and "http://landing-page1.com" now consistently reverts to https://www.default.com, while "http://www.landing-page1.com" works as intended (showing the content for "http://sub1.example.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using 3rd party plugin: https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator to create a new alias. Seems superfluous, given WP's built-in domain mapping, but it does the trick.